# CAML - how important is it?

Tags: caml

What is your experience when you go dealing with caml coding? Do you have to do lots of caml coding or is it compulsory to enable to read only?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to develop applications that works a lot with lists and list items, CAML is in many cases crucial.

Not only does it have better performance than alternative solutions (like say LINQ or loops), once you grasp it it is very easy to filter and order data (and to only retrieve the fields that you need) which in turn means less data transfer and less pressure on SQL and web servers.